# Transport service - what does 'PollerThread is timing out' mean?

Tags: 2009, publishing

We are having trouble getting a new environment working and i am seeing the message 'PollerThread is timing out because of inactivity, with empty tracking list, timepassed: 300172' in the transport log.

I assume that its means that the poller has not received a reply from the 'deployer'.

I am waiting for other colleagues to let me know what is happening at the other end of the wire.

We are using Tridion 2009 and HTTPS protocol.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't say I ever remember seeing this error. Is it an error message? Is it also accompanied by any other messages (i.e. in the CM - poller exceeded maximum number of polling attempts)?

Answer (score 4):

In Tridion 2009, the log message:

> PollerThread is timing out because of inactivity, with empty tracking list, timepassed:XXXXX

is not an error message. It simply means that the Transport service does not have anything to do and did not have anything to do since the last time it had something to do. This interval is configurable by setting the `Interval` attribute on the Poller configuration and is 30 seconds by default.

Answer (score 0):

It could mean that the folders are full of failed actions so the Poller cannot see anything new in the lists?

Comment: This got flagged as "not an answer". I think this is just the automatic "anything that short can't be an answer" algorithm kicking in. I've marked it as an inappropriate flag, but I do think a bit of extra detail would help to make the value of your answer more obvious.

Comment: It is a very imprecise and probably incorrect answer, but an answer nonetheless..